# Using CASE in Mysql to set value to an Alias field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have 2 tables in Mysql which looks as follows

Table 1

```
   ID   YEARMONTH
  ------------------
   1    201210
   2    201211
   3    201212
```

Table2

```
  ID  YEARMONTH  GRADE  DESIG
 --------------------------------
  1    201210     G1     NULL
  2    201210     G1     D2
  3    201212     G1     D1
```

I am trying to set a new field (named FLAG) in table1 which will be Y if rows exist for t1.YEARMONTH in T2 else N

I want the following Result in T1

```
ID YEARMONTH FLAG
---------------------
1  201210    Y  
2  201211    N
3  201212    Y
```

I have tried the following Query

```
SELECT
  T1.ID,
  T1.YEARMONTH,
  CASE COUNT(T2.ID)
    WHEN (SELECT
        COUNT(T2.ID)
      FROM TABLE2 T2)
      > 0 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END AS flag
FROM TABLE1 T1,
     table2 T2;
```

But it produces the following output

```
 ID   YEARMONTH  FLAG
 ---------------------------
 1    201210     N
```

I don't know where my mistake lies. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the below query:

```
SELECT
  T1.ID, T1.YEARMONTH,
  (CASE
    WHEN COUNT(T2.ID) > 0 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END) AS FLAG
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.YEARMONTH = T2.YEARMONTH
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.YEARMONTH
```

You can see the required output here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/162855/12

Comment: @sweetu514 I updated my answer as your need. Can you please see my answer.

Comment: @sweetu514 You should also tick mark and accept the answer as it is the right answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

**TRY THIS:** Using `CASE` with `LEFT JOIN` you can check the existence of t1.yearmonth in t2.yearmonth and generate the flag column accordingly

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, 
    t1.yearmonth, 
    (CASE WHEN t2.yearmonth IS NOT NULL THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END) flag
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.yearmonth = t2.yearmonth
```